# How to mock property set in constructor

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

let's say I have a class with the following constructor:

```
public class MyImpl extends Abstract<Foo> {

    @Autowired
    private FooClass foo;

    private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public MyImpl(String name, int num) {
        super(name);
        this.executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num);

    }
```

Somewhere this class has the following method:

```
    @Override
    public void doThis() {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> foo.doMethod());
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        super.doThis();
    }
```

Now, I want to test that foo.doMethod has been called 4 times **and** that `executor.execute(any())` and `executor.shutdown()` have been called 4 times as well.

So far I have

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Executors.class)
public class MyImplTest {

    private static final int NUM = 4;

    @Mock
    private FooClass foo;
    @Mock
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyImpl imyImpl = new MyImpl("Name", NUM);

    @Test
    public void shouldCallFourTimes() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Executors.class);
        when(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM)).thenReturn(foo);

        myImpl.doThis();

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM);
        verify(foo, times(NUM)).doMethod());

    }
```

However this is not working. Mockito says there haven't been any interaction with my mock Executors.
Since the @Autowired dependencies are not part of the constructor, I need to specify the constructor in the field with @InjectMocks. However, then by the time I `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Executors.class)`, the constructor of MyImpl has already created its own executor through a "real" `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`.

Any idea how I can solve this?

UPDATE:
Apparently it's not a big deal to change the design and I now have the following:

```
public class MyImpl extends Abstract<Foo> {

    @Autowired
    private FooClass foo;

    private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public MyImpl(String name, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        super(name);
        this.executor = executor;
}
```

test:

```
@Mock
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
@InjectMocks
private MyImpl imyImpl = new MyImpl("Name", executor);
```

However, the `executor` is somehow null when arriving to the constructor.

Comment: you should not create new object with 'new MyImpl("Name", NUM)' , @InjectMocks  automatically instantiates a one

Comment: If I don't do that, Mockito will complain that MyImpl has no default constructor. Note that `FooClass foo` is not passed as a parameter to the constructor

Comment: some explanation on how would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: You got your answer already ( I would have suggested the same as SpaceTrucker). Anyway, you might want to check out these videos to improve your skills of writing testable code: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the design of `MyImpl`.

Instead of creating the thread pool executor in the constructor, it should be passed to it. You can put a static factory method for your current contructor in place so that you still have the ability to create an instance with the same arguments you are using now.

Why do you need the cast to `ThreadPoolExecutor`? This lets you depend on a specific implementation. If you don't need this, you are better of with `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`.

Then you have everything in place to use just plain mockito with an ordinary `ExecutorService` mock.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to think that's the only way

Comment: I am running into other problems now though... I updated the question

Comment: @user3083022 Don't use `@InjectMocks` in this case. Create the instance directly in your test case. At the time when the constructor is called Mockito didn't have a chance to evaluate the `@Mock` annotation.

Comment: But then the dependencies I'm trying to mock with @Mock (`foo` in this case) won't be injected into my MyImpl instance, right?

Comment: @user3083022 correct. You would need to pass all dependencies via the contructor then. Depending on the circumstances, it would also be possible to provide all dependencies via dependency injection. So you would have a `@Autowire private ExecutorService executor` field.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. I have tried setting all the dependencies with `Whitebox.setInternalState` but I'm getting a weird behavior

Comment: Fixed that, the weird behaviour was caused by something else. Basically used `Whitebox.setInternalState` in order to inject the mocked dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem would be your mock classes does not get injected,

you may try something like this,

```
@Mock
private FooClass foo;
@Mock
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

private MyImpl imyImpl;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   imyImpl = new MyImpl("Name", NUM);
   impl.setFoo(foo);
   impl.setExecutor(executor);
}
```

//test

Comment: I don't want to allow to set the executor from the outside